# adding a button variable inside jquery append statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, append

I am trying to append new bootstrap list group items and within them containing a button using a `for` loop.

```
testdiv.append("<a class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'> "
    + "<h6 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + value + "</h6>"
    + "<p class='list-group-item-text'>This requires approval</p>"
    + "<button onclick='approveReq("+ value +")' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Approve</button> </a>");
```

The `value` is a variable that is being created in a `for` loop therefore each time it would produce a different result. The `onclick='approveReq("+ value +")'` should take in this value as the function `approveReq(value)` requires it.

I am not sure I am explaining this well at all, any help?

Comment: What's your question/issue ??

Comment: you should append in for loop?

Comment: Try this: `onclick='approveReq(\""+ value +"\")'`. But really, I would use jQuery to create and append elements instead of using string concatenation.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @JasonP that has worked a treat! thank you. How would I go about using jQuery to create and append elements as you suggest?

Comment: @user3480478 Something like `$('<button />).attr('type', 'button').data('value', value).addClass('btn btn-primary').text('Approve').on('click', approveReq).appendTo(testDiv)`. Then your click handler would get the value from `$(this).data('value')`. Your current solution will break if `value` ever contains quotes.

Comment: I will try this out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script 

    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var testdiv = document.getElementById('abcd');
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var str = "";
       for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        str+="<a class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'> "
        + "<h6 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + i + "</h6>"
        + "<p class='list-group-item-text'>This requires approval</p>"
        + "<button onclick='approveReq("+ i +")' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Approve</button> </a>";
      }
    $('#abcd').append(str);
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="list-group" id="abcd">

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this what you are expecting
Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/NAEZpd)